# redux-sagas callback (aka sagas and setState)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to set form loading state (spinner icon, disable input) when the user submits the form, and clear that state when the action completes or fails. Currently I am storing this state in my store, which involves creating an action creator and reducer, which is annoying for a few reasons:

1. It's a lot more work than simply calling `this.setState`
2. It's more difficult to reason about
3. I don't really want to store local component state in my store

Essentially I want to do this within my form component:

```
handleFormSubmitted() {
  this.setState({ isSaving: true })
  this.props.dispatchSaveForm({ formData: this.props.formData })
    .finally(() => this.setState({ isSaving: false }))
}
```

Comment: The whole point of using redux saga is about `side effects`, In stead of listening response from dispatch here, you probably should set the flag in the store, and map the flag from store state to your local props, and render a spinner if you want. once saga completed the requesting, the flag will be reset and the store will be updated, which will trigger the local props updated via your map function, and the component will be updated accordingly.

Comment: amen @Takahiro! The sentence that has killed me is "I don't really want to store local component state in my store".

Comment: @Josep, that's why the post was devoted as an anti-pattern, i think. :) the fetching state is definitely not a `local` state in `side-effects`. :-p

Comment: I guess so @Takahiro ... I mean, don't get me wrong. I think that it's totally legit to not use redux and have a container for that form component that handles the side-effects and the state related with that form. But if you have chosen redux and redux-saga... Then why would you want to do that? Also, what if there is an error? Don't you want the rest of your app to know that? What if later on you also have to disable a button that's somewhere else while the request is taking place? In a redux app: keeping track of an ongoing request is not "local component state".

Comment: @Josep, totally agree, you're not wrong. React is a thing letting front-end developers thinking in a different way. That's someone says React might be easier for developers who don't have any existing knowledge of other javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that with redux-saga. What you are trying to do there goes against the basic principles of redux-saga.

`redux-saga` aims to be reactive by treating actions like events that describe what's happening in your app... So that other sagas (usually "watchers" using `take`) or the rootReducer can subscribe to those actions/events and do what they need to do...

Because of that `redux-saga` -unlike `redux-thunk` and `redux-promise`-
 doesn't change the behaviour of the `dispatch` method... So, with redux saga when you dispatch, you dispatch, and the reducers and the sagas are subscribed to the dispatched actions. But the `dispatch` method won't return a promise like it happens when you use other middlewares/store-enhancers.

So, the only way that `redux-saga` has to let the rest of the app know that the request of your form has finished is by dispatching an action (using the `put` effect) whenever that request finishes or errors, right? So, how could you possibly know directly from inside the component if a specific action has been dispatched?

Unless you make your own middleware (or you use a separate one) with a connector component: there is no way for you to subscribe to concrete actions inside a component.

Sure, you could access the context directly in order to get a hold of your redux store, and then you could use [the redux `subscribe` method](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) directly, but the listener function won't tell you what's the action that got dispatched. It will just get invoked when an action (any action) gets dispatched... maybe you could check if some property of the state has changed, but that's insane. So, unless you want to go down that route, which is crazy: you can't do that using redux-saga.

If you wanted to do something like that (which IMHO is not a very good idea) you would have to do it without using redux-saga. A possible way to do it could be something along the lines of:

```
handleFormSubmitted() {
  this.setState({ isSaving: true })
  yourFetchCall({ formData: this.props.formData })
    .then(payload => this.props.dispatchFormSaved(payload))
    .catch(error => this.props.dispatchSavingFormErrored(error))
    .finally(() => this.setState({ isSaving: false }))
}
```