# Alternative approach of updating state immediately in React Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

There are a lot of answers to updating the state immediately using `useEffect` but I do not need the data on load as `useEffect` can not be used within a function. What I am trying to do? I am calling a `getData` action and in saga I am using `setData` to update a state. This is an `onClick` function. Here is my Code.

**myPage.jsx**

```
export const MyPage = props => {
    ...
    const { data } = useSelector(state => state.reducer)

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const onClick = () => {
        dispatch(getData())
        console.log(data)
    }
    ...
}
```

**slice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    data: null
}

export const mySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'mySlice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getData: ( name ) => {
            return name
        },
        setData: (state, action) => {
            state.data = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const {
    getData,
    setData
} = mySlice.actions

export default mySlice.reducer
```

**saga.js**

```
import {fetchData} from './api'

function* loadDataAsync({payload}) {
  try {
    const query = GQL_PARAMS.GET_DATA_QUERY;
    const response = yield call(fetchData, url, query, payload)
    if (response.status === 200) {
      yield put(setData(response.data.data))
    } else {
      console.log(response.status);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function* loadData() {
  yield takeLatest(getData.type, loadDataAsync);
}

export const Saga = [
  fork(loadData)
];
```

**api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

let callAPI = async ( url, query, variables ) => {
    return await axios.post(url, {
        query: query,
        variables: variables
    })
}

export const fetchData = async (url, query, variables) => callAPI( url, query, variables )
```

**rootSaga.js**

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { Saga } from './saga'

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([...Saga])
}
```

When I am clicking on the button it is returning the previous data as we all know by the architecture of react redux saga a re-render is needed to get the value and the data will not update state immediately.

I just want to know, by using this same architecture is there any way around or shortcut hack to get the data just on click. Something like imposing a fake render or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856609/getting-callbacks-from-redux-saga

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have added a callback function and added to my saga with payload. It still returning previous sate

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Update the state immediately after performing an action and use the data such as `console.log(data)`. In my case, it is showing previous data.

Comment: @slideshowp2 the callback should work, are you reading the data that you get from the callback? Of course the component state will be the same, but the data from callback should be the new one if you did everything correctly.

Comment: Also, take a look at this package https://github.com/kutlugsahin/redux-saga-callback. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076600/how-to-achieve-callbacks-in-redux-saga

Comment: @slideshowp2, I have installed the package but I am unable to dispatch. I am using Redux Toolkit. Hence my dispatch call is like `dispatch(myAction({url: url, query: query })`. From documentation of that package the dispatch should have a type and a function like this `dispatch({type: 'FETCH_USERS', onComplete: onCompleted,});` So, in my case how can I call the dispatch method?

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense: `reducers: { getData: ( name ) => { return name },`.  You are going to overwrite the entire slice state with that return statement.  It seems like you're kind of new to this? You might be trying to run before you can walk. redux-saga is a beast and it's overkill for the vast majority of situations.  I personally find the generator syntax really hard to deal with compared to promises.  Have you tried [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)?

Comment: Reading your question again, I am confident that thunks are a better solution.  `redux-thunk` middleware (included in redux-toolkit) makes it so that dispatching a thunk returns a `Promise`.  That means you can do something like this (basically) `const onClick = async () => { const nextData = await dispatch(getData()); console.log(nextData); }`.

Comment: Too late to edit my comment but I was incorrect when I said that `getData: ( name ) => { return name }` would overwrite your state.  It's just confusing because your `name` variable is actually the `state`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using promises/callbacks.

```
const var_callback = data => console.log("Callback Data",data)
dispatch({type: your_action, var_callback})

onChange(your_action, function(action) {
  action.callback({foo: 'bar'});
})
```

Comment: ```the callback should work, are you reading the data that you get from the callback? Of course the component state will be the same, but the data from callback should be the new one if you did everything correctly. ``` stated by Martin Kedlec